# Upgraded server to PHP 5.3.28 and Images stopped working

Tags: product, server-setup, media, third-party-module, server

We upgraded the server to PHP 5.2.28 (Rackspace) and suddenly our full size images stopped working. By stop working I mean it did not render and the page load stopped at the point of the full size image loading. (White screen) No error message in any logs

The site has a custom OnePica image gallery loaded. We are debugging but I am hoping someone as a light bulb light that comes on as soon as they read this :)

Comment: Brent! You know better!  What does "not working" mean?  Are there no image tags on the page?  Are there image tags but the image URLs 404? 503? 500?  Return a blank image? etc.

Comment: Sorry Alan, I typed this in haste. It was the full size image being rendered by Magento. It turns out Rackspace upgraded PHP but failed to install  PHP GD. Once we installed that :: MAGIC!

Comment: Don't forget to answer you own question for future searchers and I'll get the oversight removed from your permeant record. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution:

Rackspace installed their package of Ioncube loader and during the installation they realized the version of PHP also needed to be upgraded. Somehow they missed the fact that some of the php modules also had to be installed. The module in question is/was PHP GD